# Forward file data to another server

Tags: php, file, upload, server

I have one identical php page on two servers which looks like this:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == "1.2.3.4"){ //1.2.3.4 = server1 local ip
    if($alreadyUploadedBytesToday + $_FILES["fileUpload"]["size"] > $allowedBytesToday){
        //send $_FILES data to server2
    }
}
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)
?>
```

I want to be able to forward the `$_FILES` `POST` data to another server with more bandwidth if over the file upload size is greater than `allowedBytesToday` bytes.

Unfortunately all variables are dynamic so I would not be able to do this client side.

Should I be using CURL? And if so will that not mean that the file is in effect uploaded twice?

Comment: By the time your PHP script starts, the file has already been uploaded to the server and is sat in your temp folder waiting to be handled.

Comment: Does that mean that anyone can send fake $_file post requests to my server using up it's bandwidth?